# Azure keyvault, request for multiple secrets

Tags: node.js, azure-keyvault

Im making use of the following node library [azure-keyvault](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-keyvault) to get retrieve stored secrets from azure keyvault. Ive only found the `client.getSecret` api exposed to retrieve a secret value. Im searching for a way to retrieve multiple secret values in one call. I hav'nt found one yet. Is there a way to do this that i'm missing or its simply not supported.

Answer (score 2):

```
const { SecretClient } = require('@azure/keyvault-secrets')
const client = new SecretClient(
        `https://${KEYVAULT_NAME}.vault.azure.net`,
        new DefaultAzureCredential()
)
const [secret1, secret2] = await Promise.all([
         client.getSecret(`secret1`),
         client.getSecret(`secret2`)
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete code for getting the multiple client secret at once:

```
var credentials = new KeyVault.KeyVaultCredentials(authenticator);
var client = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(credentials);

client.setSecret(vaultUri, 'mysecret', 'my password', options, function (err, secretBundle) {

  // List all secrets
  var parsedId = KeyVault.parseSecretIdentifier(secretBundle.id);
  client.getSecrets(parsedId.vault, parsedId.name, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var loop = function (nextLink) {
      if (nextLink !== null && nextLink !== undefined) {
        client.getSecretsNext(nextLink, function (err, res) {
          console.log(res);
          loop(res.nextLink);
        });
      }
    };

    console.log(result);
    loop(result.nextLink);
  });
});
```

You can find the complete reference for azure key vault using node js below:

http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-keyvault/latest/KeyVaultClient.html#getSecrets

http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-keyvault/latest/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [read-azure-secrets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-azure-secrets) npm package which will return all secrets to you.
E.g.

```
    const secretClient = require('read-azure-secrets');

    async function loadKeyVaultValues() {

        let applicationID = '';
        let applicationSecret = '';
        let vaultURL = 'https://<your-key-vault-name>.vault.azure.net/';
        let secrets = await secretClient.getSecrets(applicationID, applicationSecret, vaultURL);

        secrets.forEach(secret => {
            console.log(secret);
        });

    }

loadKeyVaultValues();
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what information about the secret you want to fetch so I am going to assume that you are looking for the secret's value. I am also going to assume you are looking to minimize network traffic for fetching multiple secrets (either for costs or for performance).

Looking at the [Azure REST API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/keyvault/) while there is a route to list multiple secrets it only provides the secret identifier and metadata about the secret (attributes, tags, etc). So if you want to get the secret's value (the actual secret) you will need to make individual calls although get-secrets route can be used to find all the secrets stored in the Key Vault.

As far as the client library, `@azure/keyvault-secrets` maps pretty closely to the REST API it supports so it will not provide a method that fetches multiple secrets. Even if it did, it would just be a facade over multiple network calls so it would not help reduce the number of network trips.

So to answer your question - it does not look possible today unless all you want is metadata about the secret and not the secret value itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `client.getSecrets(..)` method exposed by the REST Api.

Kindly go through the following useful blog, in which all methods have been implemented.

LINK: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/platform-as-a-service/using-azure-keyvault-with-node-js/

Comment: the response returned by `getSecrets` contains objects that don't include the value of the secret.